# Can we publish a message to SNS topic using a lambda function written in Go language?

Tags: aws-lambda, amazon-sns, aws-lambda-go

I had a lambda function written in Golang. And I was trying to publish a message to SNS topic from lambda function before  the lambda is executed . Is it possible to do so?

Comment: You can invoke lambda by SNS.

Comment: Are you  referring to using SNS to trigger lambda ? I was looking for other way around . Wanted to publish the message to SNS using lambda function . I probably might have to use AWS SDK , however I do not know if it is possible for lambda backed by Golang .

Comment: But you need to publish msg before the lambda is executed. right ?

Comment: Probably my wording was bit confusing . I am fine if message is published just after lambda is triggered, at very beginning of function. Message would be something  like : “Lambda just got triggered”

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can publish a message to SNS topic using a lambda function written in Go language.

You can use the [AWS SDK for GO](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdk-for-go/api/service/sns/)

Answer (score -1):

Although Arafat's answer is absolutely correct but if someone is really stuck here then for a detailed and step by step information on how to connect SNS with lambda function written in GoLang, can refer to : https://medium.com/@madhavchaturvedi/awesomeness-of-golang-aws-lambda-d6bd08131117